# What is the exact meaning of the "oh so <adjective>" idiom?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I routinely find this expression in newspaper, magazines, blogs... My guess is that it's used to report a widely shared opinion, but I couldn't find any confirmation of this. Or maybe it's just used to emphasize the adjective? I'm afraid I might be missing a subtelty here.

Here are a few examples from the first page of googling "oh so *":

- Paul Ryan's oh-so-clever jab at Jay Cutler
- Chivas USA came oh so close to getting the first goal of the match
- The movie-star-handsome [...] stung with that oh-so-direct comeuppance
- Robert Pattinson Oh So Lonely: 'No One Ever Calls Or Texts Me!'
- An Oh-So-British Affair Projects a Fresh, Antique Charm
- LaPorta made an oh-so-costly error in the game
- Finally, the long, oh so very long flight back to Vancouver

‎

Comment: Can you give some more context? I'm having trouble thinking of examples of this pattern.

Comment: Well, as I said, I find it routinely; downvoting just because of this seems quite a bit harsh.

Comment: maybe it's just a kind of slang use of the word to make it easier to reflect a more real just regular and casual way that people talk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Oh-so" means "very", but with the implication of certain emotion. The "oh" caries similar meaning to a sigh. It can imply sarcasm, relief, frustration, etc.

Comment: So it's context dependent, isn't it? And sarcasm seems to be its most prominent use.

Comment: Yes indeed, exactly as you said.

Comment: @UncleZeiv no, sarcasm isn't "its most prominent use". See [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/478143), which I wrote primarily to address the question of whether the expression has an element of sarcasm :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it means "very" or "extremely". It is used to modify an adjective or adverb.

> "Paul Ryan's oh-so-clever jab at Jay Cutler"

Becomes

> "Paul Ryan's very clever jab."

Another example

> "LaPorta made an oh-so-costly error in the game"
>
> "LaPorta made an extremely costly error in the game"

Comment: Possibly because it's a somewhat 'quirky' idiom in the first place, **oh-so** often gets used in sarcastic / scornful / jocular contexts.

Comment: I'd read the *"oh-so-clever"* sentence as *"Paul Ryan thought his jab was very clever, but it was actually rather lame"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure about "often" in such contexts - none of the given examples seem to fit this description. But certainly when such a context exists, *oh-so-* serves as a useful means of emphasising the sarcasm/scorn/joke. See [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/478143), which I wrote primarily to address the question of whether the expression has an element of sarcasm :-)

Answer (score 2):

### What does "oh-so-" mean?

The expression "oh-so-" is an [intensifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier), a linguistic term for a modifier that "serves to enhance and give additional emotional context to the word it modifies". *So* is itself an intensifier, but it can normally only be used predicatively - "that joke was so clever" but not "the so clever joke". However, the idiomatic addition of *oh* enables *so* to be used attributively (though *why*, I'm not sure!): "the oh so clever joke." [Note that some style guides require an adjectival phrase before a noun to be hyphenated if the first element isn't an adverb ending in -ly; hence *oh-so-clever jab* but "that jab was oh so clever".]

The "oh" in the expression gives the added sense of a sigh or gasp (depending on context), heightening the emotional content of the expression.

We would therefore interpret *oh-so-lonely* as something like "so lonely it made me sigh", and *oh-so-clever* as "so clever it made me gasp".

### Does it indicate sarcasm?

A number of answers have suggested that the addition "oh-so-" is often used in a sarcastic context. This is *not* the case - at least, it's no more true than the use of "very" or any other intensifier. Cambridge Dictionary defines [sarcasm](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sarcasm) as

> the use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say,
>   made in order to hurt someone's feelings or to criticize something in
>   a humorous way:
>   *"You have been working hard," he said with heavy sarcasm, as he looked at the empty page.*

**None** of the examples given in the question are sarcastic in tone. In each case, "oh-so-" is used in a straightforward way to intensify the following word.

### What about that Ryan-Cutler line?

Let's have a look at the first example in particular, where the confusion may lie in failing to differentiate the *description* of Ryan's jab from the actual jab (the pointed comment) itself.

The expression "Paul Ryan's oh-so-clever jab at Jay Cutler" was the headline of an [NFL (American football) article](http://www.espn.com/blog/nfcnorth/post/_/id/27027/paul-ryans-oh-so-clever-jab-at-jay-cutler) by sports journalist Kevin Seifert. The body of the article explains the context:

> What I will do, however, is draw your attention to noted funnyman Paul
>   Ryan, the Wisconsin congressman who is also the House Budget Committee
>   chairman. Ryan has gained a bit of fame recently during the federal
>   government's budget battle, and on Monday he couldn't resist a shot at
>   Bears quarterback Jay Cutler during a speech to the Economic Club of
>   Chicago.
>
> The Washington Examiner has the full text of Ryan's prepared remarks,
>   which he apparently embellished a bit during the actual speech. Fox
>   News quoted him this way:
>
> > "I want to thank you all for inviting me to speak. It was especially
> >     gracious of you to host me, even though I'm a Packers fan and I assume
> >     most of you are Bears fans. But that doesn't mean we can't work
> >     together. As chairman of the House Budget Committee, I stand ready to
> >     do whatever it takes to help you re-sign Jay Cutler.
> >
> > "I'm here to talk about the economy today -- about the need to get
> >     four quarters of strong, consistent performance.
> >
> > "That wasn't another Jay Cutler joke, I swear. It could be, but it's
> >     not."

Ryan himself was using [verbal irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Verbal_irony) - defined by Abrams and Hartman as "a statement in which the meaning that a speaker employs is sharply different from the meaning that is ostensibly expressed" - and his comment about four quarters of strong performance was **particularly clever**, since this was ostensibly about a financial year divided into four quarters, but a savvy audience would see the allusion to four quarters of a football game.

In this context, the use of "oh-so-clever" in Seifert's headline is not in the least sarcastic - it's entirely factual. The headline should be interpreted as: *Ryan made a pointed comment about Cutler that was so clever it made me gasp.*

Answer (score 1):

Example: Paul Ryan's oh-so-clever jab at Jay Cutler

"Oh, so clever" is a thought on it's own, a saying that could stand by itself and may have even been uttered when the jab itself was uttered. However, using that phrase implies that the jab had to be quite cleaver indeed. Thus, in this example, the idiom emphasizes the adjective with the underlying assumption of the phrase.

Example: Chivas USA came oh so close to getting the first goal of the match

Again, "Oh, so close" was likely said (or at least thought) by a large portion of those involved, and again, the phrase implies that the goal was exceptionally close and imparts that state to the adjective.

Answer (score -1):

I find out these precisions (pardon my... english! because I'm a frog...) in
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=oh%20so

oh so
used in sarcastic manner to comment on a personality trait or to insult someone who is bragging about
Bob: i have lots of black friends so i can use the word n*gger
Danny: your oh so open minded

Bob: hitler wrote the second half of the bible
Danny: your oh so educated

And in a comic book, I found this expression writen on interrogative mode:
A: “What are you raving about? I never did anything to you!”
B: “Oh so?”
Can Somebody help me to specicy this meaning?
Thanks

Comment: Oliver, it's not the "oh-so-" itself that creates the sarcasm, it's the *other* part of the expression, i.e. "open-minded" and "educated". The "oh-so-" just intensifies the expression, i.e. drawing greater attention to the sarcasm of the other word. See [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/478143), which I wrote primarily to address the question of whether the expression has an element of sarcasm :-)

Answer (score -1):

I would say the use of the expression in your examples is one of **derision**, not directly sarcasm.

The expression, in normal terms, just means an sigh, admiring/lamenting something for being “very” (adjective) such as “My little nephew is oh so cute”.  The speaker is definitely touched/moved.

All your examples, except the first, are without any sarcasm, just emotion.

When sarcasm is used, note that it does not mean a negation of the fact, only a negation of the speaker’s admiration for it. For example, it is not meant that Paul Ryan’s jab was not actually clever. Rather, that it was too clever for the speaker’s admiration, and invited derision instead.

1. **Paul Ryan's oh-so-clever jab at Jay Cutler**

   2. Chivas USA came oh so
      close to getting the first goal of the match
   3. The movie-star-handsome
      [...] stung with that oh-so-direct comeuppance
   4. Robert Pattinson Oh
      So Lonely: 'No One Ever Calls Or Texts Me!'
   5. An Oh-So-British Affair
      Projects a Fresh, Antique Charm
   6. LaPorta made an oh-so-costly error
      in the game
   7. Finally, the long, oh so very long flight back to
      Vancouver

Comment: You might like to include a definition of *derision* in your answer, as none of its meanings I'm aware of suit this question. And your explanation of *sarcasm* is also wrong: sarcasm *relies* on negation, it's an ironic statement of the opposite.